# Cannot build a project due to play-services-base-17.1.0.aar transformation error

Tags: android-studio, gradle, google-play-services, daemon

So basically I haven't opened my Android Studio project for almost a year and this time was the time for it to be opened and built. After updating Android Studio and all of the project's plugins, I finally reach this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Me\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d92a27efcac738b4f280b9ad0c07bda7\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\Me\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d92a27efcac738b4f280b9ad0c07bda7\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
```

I hope someone could help me resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**update 07 May 2021**
With Android Studio 4.2 and the corresponding android gradle plugin v4.2.0 (which requires gradle 6.7.1) the build now works for me also on my older AMD.
So I guess the problem has been fixed :)
(would be great if someone else can confirm via comment)

**original answer**

Hi have exactly the same issue.
The project builds on 2 of 3 tested PCs. The only difference I see is, that is not working on an older AMD processor. The PCs its working with have both Intel CPUs (an older i7, 2. Gen, and a new i7). All three PCs are running with Windows 10 Pro.
My dev environment is set up equally on all 3 PCs.

I hope this information helps to find a maybe better solution.
The only solution I found is to go back to a previous version of the Gradle plugin and Gradle itself.

In gradle-wrapper properties I defined Gradle version 6.1.1

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip

And in the project build.gradle I set version 4.0.2

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'

Comment: upgrading to gradle plugin v4.2.0 from v4.1.0 and downgrading to gradle 6.7.1 from gradle 6.9 solved my problem. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. Invalidate Cache / Restart
2. Clean Project
3. Rebuild Project

Answer (score 0):

Along same lines: I too am getting this same error but oddly, my project is stored on OneDrive so I can access it/modify it from different locations. The SAME project builds, installs and runs with no issue at one location (with my phone connected to computer), but the error shown above takes place when accessing the same files from the other location (with the same phone connected).

The same version of Android Studio is being used at both locations as well. This was not an issue with this same project a few days ago (i.e. - it ran properly from both locations until recently)

The solution offered previously here does not fix the issue.

Would not normally put this response here but thought perhaps my experience with the same error message could help shed some light on what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

the same topic is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64890769/android-studio-4-1-1-where-i-get-detal-about-error-a-failure-occurred-while-exe). I have the same behavior the same project builds without a problem on i7. But produces an error on an old AMD processor.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.