# Android Studio 4.1.1 Where i get detal about error? A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

Tags: android-studio

Hi,


after upgrading to Android Studio 4.1.1

and classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'

I get an error for Rebuild Project, Debug  and Run

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
```

**i try**

- org.gradle.jvmargs = -Xmx4608m
- Invalidate and restart
- Make Project(without error)
- Clean Project

**i use**

Windows10

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip

Where i get detal about error?

How fix this?

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fDPJ.png)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and use this to fix.

In gradle-wrapper properties I defined Gradle version 6.1.1

`distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip`

And in the project build.gradle I set version 4.0.2

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'`

Font: [Cannot build a project due to play-services-base-17.1.0.aar transformation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64853355/cannot-build-a-project-due-to-play-services-base-17-1-0-aar-transformation-error/65126098#65126098?newreg=d978f955917d41a6a57bc7837a9c88d0)